# Azure Devops integration error in Azure DataBricks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks

I am getting following error while syncing a azure databricks notebook with an Azure DevOps repo I've linked it to:

Error while syncing Git history: Numeric value (3204746134) out of range of int? at [Source: {"id":

The repository branch specified in azure databricks is successfully created over on Azure DevOps.

I tried removing the revision history of the notebook that is no longer required to reduce the number of changes to be checked-in. This did not help to fix the error.

Comment: Try with a repository with less characters. For more details, refer https://forums.databricks.com/questions/16309/azure-devops-integration-fails.html

Answer (score -1):

There was error while syncing git repo with Azure databricks when repo size is above 3 GB. This was confirmed by the products team and a fix has been deployed.